# how to work with dict() when using depth first search tree

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

Given:

```
class NoName:
  def __init__(self):
     self.some_dict = {}

  def add_new_node(self, label):
    self.some_dict[label] = {}
```

Consider I call the class how would I use the add_new_node method ? what prams will I need to pass in the add_new_node method ?

```
NoName.add_new_node('a':1)
```

obviously, this will not work. I need to understand how to make such positional arguments work.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have made an update to the post, please take a look.

Comment: I saw your edit. Positional args is easy in python. You call it by doing `instance.add_new_node(label=1)`

Comment: The question seems to have nothing to do with dfs anyway.

Comment: If I enter label=1 then I get an error stating: positional argument self is missing. I have a __repr__ method in my class as well.

Comment: I see that you are new to Python. For classes in python, you have to create an instance by calling `a = NoName()` and then call `a.add_new_node(label='something')`. Then Jaky's answer seem to have what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It's this what you are looking for?

```
class NoName:
  def __init__(self):
     self.some_dict = {}

  def add_new_pair_key_value(self, node, value):
    self.some_dict[node] = value

  def add_new_whole_node(self, whole_node):
    self.some_dict.update(whole_node)

noname = NoName()
noname.add_new_pair_key_value('new_node', 'new_value')
print(noname.some_dict)

noname.add_new_whole_node({'label': {'new_whole_key': 'new_node_value'}})
print(noname.some_dict)
```

output first print:

```
{'new_node': 'new_value'}
```

output second print:

```
{'new_node': 'new_value', 'label': {'new_whole_key': 'new_node_value'}}
```

Comment: tried calling this:  noName.add_new_Node(label={'new_whole_key': 'new_node_value'}), It gives an error saying- add_new_Node() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.

Comment: I edited, better now? I mean, if you have another object (node) you can do it with update, is that what you wanted?